# Stabilizer $V_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ on Tetrahedron Template

Tags: stabilizer

Using Burnside I have found $65$ ways to give the faces of a tetrahedron $1$,$2$ or $3$ dots (like a dice). Now I have to draw these dots on the tetrahedron such that the stabilizer is $V_4$ or $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. I was told that I should only use the asymmetric  dots (so $2$ dots). I don't understand why and how to do this. The right answer is, according to my teacher,

[image]

I would like to try this for arrows and different colours too.